# nvprof R gputools code never ends

Tags: r, gpgpu, nvprof

I am trying to run "nvprof" from command line on R. Here is how I am doing it:

./nvprof --print-gpu-trace --devices 0 --analysis-metrics --export-profile /home/xxxxx/%p R

This gives me a R prompt and i write R code. I can do with Rscript too.

Problem i see is when i give --analysis-metrics option it gives me lots of lines similar to 
  ==44041== Replaying kernel "void ger_kernel(cublasGerParams)"

And R process never ends. I am not sure what I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nvprof doesn't modify process exit behavior, so I think you're just suffering from slowness because your app invokes a lot of kernels. You have two options to speed this up.

**1. Selectively profiling metrics**

The `--analysis-metrics` option enables collection of a number of metrics, which requires kernels to be replayed - collecting a different set of metrics for each kernel run.

If your application has a lot of kernel invocations, this can take time. I'd suggest you query the available metrics with the `nvprof --query-metrics` command, and then manually choose the metrics you are interested in.

Once you know which metrics you want, you can query them using `nvprof -m metric_1,metric_2,...`. This way, the application will profile less metrics, hence requiring less replays, and running faster.

**2. Selectively profiling kernels**

Alternatively, you can only profile a specific kernel using the `--kernels <context id/name>:<stream id/name>:<kernel name>:<invocation>` option.

For example, `nvprof --kernels ::foo:2 --analysis-metrics ./your_cuda_app` will profile all analysis metrics for the kernel whose name contains the string `foo`, and only on its second invocation. This option takes regular expressions, and is quite powerful.

---

You can mix and match the above two approaches to speed up profiling. You will be able to find more help about these and other nvprof options using the command `nvprof --help`.